# Finding elements that are in strictly N of X lists

Tags: python, list

I have N lists, and would like to know which elements are present in strictly X of those lists. I understand that if I have two lists, it's rather straightforward:

```py
lst_a = [1,2,3]
lst_b = [1,2,5]

overlap = list(set(a) & set(b))
```

What if I have, say, 5 lists, and want to know which elements are in strictly 4 of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge using counters:

```
from collections import Counter

lst_a = [1,2,3]
lst_b = [1,2,5]
lsts = [lst_a, lst_b]

counter = Counter()
for lst in lsts:
    unique = set(lst)
    counter += Counter(unique)

n = 2
print(f"elements in exactly {n} lsts:")
for k, v in counter.items():
    if v == n:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @wim's code, but in a more concise manner:

```
[i for i, c in sum(map(Counter, lsts), Counter()).items() if c == 2]
```

If the items in the input lists are not unnecessarily unique you can map the lists to sets first:

```
[i for i, c in sum(map(Counter, map(set, lsts)), Counter()).items() if c == 2]
```

This returns:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Sure. Updated then.